# Recovering Windows 10 using a pen drive

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, system-recovery, recovery-partition

I recently bought a `Dell Inspiron 15 5000 (5579)` laptop and it came with Windows 10 pre-installed on it. However, I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I cloned the recovery drive into my pen drive.

If I format my SSD and install Ubuntu on it, will I be able to use the recovery (pen drive) drive to reinstall Windows 10 on the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Dell systems the preferred method to prepare for system recovery is to create recovery media using the Dell-provided tool within the OS, such as the Dell Backup and Recovery Manager. This method will be more reliable than copying the Recovery partition via other means.

Alternatively, if at such future time you would choose to reinstall Windows 10 on the machine, you could [download it directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10). If you don't want to install the extra, sometimes unwanted software included by OEMs, this method is for you. You won't have any trouble activating Windows installed via this method because Dell embedded your product key in the system firmware as required by Microsoft. Should you need any drivers after performing an install using Microsoft's media, you can visit [Dell's support site](http://www.dell.com/support) and use their system scanner or enter your Service Tag number to quickly obtain the drivers specific to your system.